# Ways to split a Number into an Array

Tags: javascript, methods, split, type-conversion

Let's say we have a number:

`let num = 969`

I'm trying to split this number into an array of digits. The first two methods do not work, but the third does. What is the difference?

```
num + ''.split('')             // '969'
num.toString() + ''.split('')  // '969'
String(num).split('')          // [ '9', '6', '9' ]
```

Comment: Because only the last `split` is called on the `num` itself. The 1st and 2nd `split` is called on `''`.

Comment: `(969 + '').split('') // 9, 6, 9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's look how it works

**num + ''.split('')** works like

1. `num` is a number
2. `''.split('')` is empty array and it's not a number
3. so, we have sum of a number and not a number, we will cast num and []
   to string
4. `num` to string is '969', `[]` to string is '' (empty)
5. '969' + '' = '969'

**num.toString() + ''.split('')** works like

1. `num.toString()` is a string
2. ''.split('') is empty array
3. so, we have sum of a string and not a string, we will cast `[]` to
   string
4. `[]` to string is '' (empty)
5. '969' + '' = '969'

**String(num).split('')** works like

1. lets cast `num` to string
2. and split it by ''
3. result of split is array ['9', '6', '9']

Answer (score 2):

Try like this, you will understand why !

```
(num + '').split('')             // [ '9', '6', '9' ]
(num.toString() + '').split('')  // [ '9', '6', '9' ]
String(num).split('')          // [ '9', '6', '9' ]
```

in the first and second lines, you split `''` (empty string).