# Split a number that looks like binary into an array when the function is a variable - do I need to convert or something?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't split a bunch of numbers when the function is a number - why? How do you do this?

I'm attempting https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-1-bits/

[Ways to split a Number into an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093956/ways-to-split-a-number-into-an-array)

Accepted answer:

> Well, let's look how it works
>
> **num + ''.split('')** works like
>
> 1. `num` is a number
> 2. `''.split('')` is empty array and it's not a number
> 3. so, we have sum of a number and not a number, we will cast num and []
>    to string
> 4. `num` to string is '969', `[]` to string is '' (empty)
> 5. '969' + '' = '969'
>
> **num.toString() + ''.split('')** works like
>
> 1. `num.toString()` is a string
> 2. ''.split('') is empty array
> 3. so, we have sum of a string and not a string, we will cast `[]` to
>    string
> 4. `[]` to string is '' (empty)
> 5. '969' + '' = '969'
>
> **String(num).split('')** works like
>
> 1. lets cast `num` to string
> 2. and split it by ''
> 3. result of split is array ['9', '6', '9']

Of course when I try it....it doesn't work:

```js
var hammingWeight = function(n) {
    let oneBits = String(n).split('');
    console.log(oneBits)
};

hammingWeight(0000011110)
```

What's going on here? Why does it not work?

```js
function hammingWeight(n) {
    let oneBits = String(n).split('');
    console.log(oneBits)
};

hammingWeight(0000011110)
```

Why doesn't this work?

```js
function hammingWeight(n) {
    let oneBits = n.toString().split('');
    console.log(oneBits)
};

hammingWeight(0000011110)
```

I am beyond confused - where are those numbers coming from?

[Binary to String in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866910/binary-to-string-in-javascript)

```js
function hammingWeight(n) {
    const oneBits = String.fromCharCode(
          ...n.split(''))
    )
    console.log(oneBits)
};

hammingWeight(0000011110)
```

Doesn't work either!

Answer (score 1):

The Leet Code website is asking for an integer, but it is counting the number of binary 1 bits.

To satisfy the provided method, you would have to: convert the number into a binary string, split it into individual bits, filter only the 1 bits, and return the length.

```js
/**
 * @param {number} n - a positive integer
 * @return {number} number of 1 bits present in the binary representation
 */
const hammingWeight = n => n.toString(2).split('').filter(v => v === '1').length

console.log(hammingWeight(11))         // 1011 => 3
console.log(hammingWeight(128))        // 10000000 => 1
console.log(hammingWeight(4294967293)) // 11111111111111111111111111111101 => 31
```

If you want to support binary string input, this is much easier. You just need to take a string argument instead of an integer.

```js
/**
 * @param {string} bin - an unsigned binary integer string
 * @return {number} number of 1 bits present in the binary representation
 */
const hammingWeight = bin => bin.split('').filter(v => v === '1').length

console.log(hammingWeight('1011'))                             //  => 3
console.log(hammingWeight('10000000'))                         //  => 1
console.log(hammingWeight('11111111111111111111111111111101')) //  => 31
```

---

### Explanation

To elaborate, your issue is that you are sending an octal integer in your example, rather than a binary string.

```js
function hammingWeight(n) {
  let oneBits = String(n).split(''); // ['4','6','8','0']
  console.log(oneBits)
};

hammingWeight(0000011110) // Same as 011110 or 4680
```

You can send this as a literal binary integer like so, but you still need to stringify it using the radix value of `2` (binary):

```js
function hammingWeight(n) {
  let oneBits = n.toString(2).split(''); // ['1','1','1','1','0']
  console.log(oneBits)
};

hammingWeight(0b0000011110) // Prefix literal binary number with '0b'
```

Comment: @Amaarockz the function is requesting a number, not a string. The value `1110` would be the input `14`. That would be an invalid parameter.

Comment: the input can't be numbers like that only 0s and 1s

Comment: what is 2 doing in toString?

Comment: @kawnah The Leet Code website states that the parameter type for `n` is `number`. A string is not a number. See: `@param {number} n - a positive integer`

Comment: @kawnah The `2` is the radix. It is telling JS to convert the decimal integer into a binary number string representation.

Comment: so can you elaborate in your answer why you can split `bin` like that but I can't with the function? I need to know exactly every detail as to why yours works and mine doesn't

Comment: "you would have to: convert the number into a binary string, split it into individual bits" I did literally exactly this and it gave me random numbers - why?

Comment: @kawnah I added an "Explanation" section at the bottom. Hopefully this helps.